# Occasionally after compiling, computer locks up

Tags: c, compilation, crash, xorg

This is a strange issue, but it happens between one and five times a month.

During development, I compile frequently (this is not the unusual part.) From time to time, running the freshly-compiled binary locks up my system. Tray clock doesn't increment, ctrl+alt+backspace doesn't kill Xorg. Totally conked.

I physically powercycle the machine and everything's OK. Application runs fine, from the same binary that murdered my machine earlier or after a no-change recompile, and I get on with my work.

But it still bothers me, largely because I have no idea what causes it. This can occur with binaries compiling with either Clang or GCC. What is going on?

Comment: Compilation is an integer problem, gets the processor to put an easy 100 watts into the case.  When is the last time you cleaned it?  Get a vacuum cleaner, open the case and suck out the dust bunnies.

Comment: Compilation takes less than a second, and this happens with single-file concept code too. My CPU is pretty well cooled, too.

Comment: So does the problem occur when you compile, or when you run your program, you tell us two different things. If it's the program, what does your program do ?

Comment: It happens when I run my program but *only immediately after a recompile.* Post edited to disambiguate.

Comment: @sudowned Get a memory checker tool, these symptoms are typical for bad RAM - or other issues with hardware.

Comment: Might see what Mprime has to say about my hardware, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say, but I have two ideas:

1) Bad RAM
  This is possible, but depending on your code, #2 might be more likely.

2) Buffer overflow bug
  If you are overwriting memory due to a bug in your code, you could be putting some bits in memory that happen to be assembly instructions as well. I would look very carefully at the code you have to see where you don't check array lengths before you write to them.

Comment: It's occurred with trivial programs as well - I spent the weekend teaching myself some of the C fundamentals two months ago, and to my horror this occurred with a program one or two steps above "hello world" in complexity. Worth noting is that this seemingly **only** happens when running a binary I compiled from C... so if it's a RAM issue, it's incredibly specific.

Comment: It could be that the way your compiler is placing your binary into memory is such that you're hitting that memory issue. I'd invest a half hour in taking out some RAM and running your binaries again...  Of course it *could* be a compiler problem too.  What are you using?

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't happen every time. Sometimes a couple times a week, then no problems for a few more weeks. I've tried to reproduce the issue intentionally and it doesn't happen. Again, this occurs with binaries built in both Clang and GCC.

Comment: Going to try mprime and see if I can verify this as a hardware issue.